# set default working directory for notebook without changing source directory

Tags: jupyter-lab

I am running jupyter lab, and would like notebooks to default to "/usr/src/app" for their working directory. If I use `--notebook-dir=/usr/src/app` when starting the server, the file browser has this directory as its root. I keep my notebooks elsewhere. Can I set only the default working directory for notebooks, without changing the root of the file browser?